# How deserialize from LocalDate and/or LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, localdate, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

I need to create a class that implements JsonbDeserializer < ZonedDateTime > , but, the data (string) to be parsed could be in this format "2021-05-31" or this format "2021-05-31T09:30:57.544797".

How could I deal with this scenario?

Comment: If the string length is 10, parse into a `LocalDate` and call `LocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId)` passing the desired time zone. If longer parse into `LocalDateTime` and call its `atZone` method.

Comment: Check out ZonedDateTime.parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter) - based on the string length, for example, you could try a different DateTimeFormatter. I think DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT may work for the longer format, whereas DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE should work for the shorter format. If none work you can write your own DateTimeFormatter.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your pieces of example data are suitable for a `ZonedDateTime` object.

## Date without time, and without zone

"2021-05-31" represents a date-only value. Use `LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-05-31" ) ;
```

If you want to make a `ZonedDateTime` of that, you’ll to assign a time-of-day and a time zone.

Perhaps you’d want the first moment of the day as the time. If so, do not assume that first moment is at 00:00:00. Some dates in some zones start at a different moment such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Date and time without zone

"2021-05-31T09:30:57.544797" represents a date with a time of day, but lacks an indicator of time zone or offset from UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-05-31T09:30:57.544797" ) ;
```

If you want to make a `ZonedDateTime` of that, assign a time zone. Be aware the time of day may change to adjust for gaps caused by anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Japan" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```